# Solve time dependent Schrödinger equation in order to find $\phi(t)$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

We study a quantum particle conned to a one-dimensional box with walls at the positions $\pm 1$. The Hilbert space of this system in the Schrödinger representation is again given by $L_2(-1,1)$.

In this Hilbert space, we consider the two functions $g_0(x):=(1+i)\exp(i \pi x)$ and $g_1(x):=\exp(i 2 \pi x)$. I've shown that $g_0$ and $g_1$ are orthogonal in $L_2([-1,1])$ and that the orthonormal states are $\phi_0=\frac{g_0(x)}{2}$ and $\phi_1=\frac{g_1(x)}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Now we consider the initial state $\phi(0)=\phi_+=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\phi_0+\phi_1)$ and assume that the time evolution of the system is given by the Hamiltonian $H=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\partial^2_x-C$.

And the superposition is given by $\Psi=\alpha \psi_0+\beta\psi_1$.

Now I have to determine $\phi(t)$ for time $t$ and the expectation value of the position operator w.r.t. $\phi(t)$.

I'm not sure how to deal with that. I think I have to use the time dependent Schrödinger equation,
$$i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi(x,t)=\left[-\frac{\hbar}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+U(t)\right]\psi(x,t),$$
where we use that $U(t)=e^{\frac{iHt}{\hbar}}$. Is that correct and how can I use that to solve for $\phi(t)$?

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/691120/2451

Answer (score -1):

It's better to write the TDSE as:

$$i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Psi(x,t)=\left[-\frac{\hbar}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+U(x,t)\right]\Psi(x,t)$$
Now assume ('Ansatz') that:

$$\Psi(x,t)=\psi(x)\phi(t)$$

Then use [separation of variables](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/SeparationofVariables.aspx) to find $\psi$ and $\phi$.